# A universal match pattern ('/**') is defined... error when trying to add spring security to project

Tags: java, spring-security

I'm trying to add spring security to my project and I've already tried to use all the solutions found on the internet, but nothing worked. Do you have any ideas??
stack trace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A universal match pattern ('/**') is defined  before other patterns in the filter chain, causing them to be ignored. Please check the ordering in your <security:http> namespace or FilterChainProxy bean configuration
    at org.springframework.security.config.http.DefaultFilterChainValidator.checkPathOrder(DefaultFilterChainValidator.java:51)
    at org.springframework.security.config.http.DefaultFilterChainValidator.validate(DefaultFilterChainValidator.java:40)
...
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<web-app ..>

    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/context.xml,
            /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

spring-security.xml:

```
<beans:beans ...>

    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">

        <intercept-url pattern="/admin**" access="hasRole('role_admin')" />

        <access-denied-handler error-page="/403" />

        <form-login
            login-page="/user/login"
            default-target-url="/index"
            authentication-failure-url="/index"
            username-parameter="username"
            password-parameter="password" />
        <logout logout-success-url="/index"  />
    </http>

    <authentication-manager>
      <authentication-provider>
        <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
          users-by-username-query=
            "select username,password from users where username=?"
          authorities-by-username-query=
            "select username, role from users join user_roles using(id_user_roles) where username =?" />
      </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

Shall I add attach some other .xml files from my project?

Comment: It looks like you might have another `<http>` element, or a `FilterChainProxy` bean definition somewhere.

Comment: Could You please help me how to do configure one of them? I did not found any understandable solution on the internet.